# Python: How to start an .EXE that will not terminate when python script terminates

Tags: python, windows, subprocess

What's the most pythonic way to start an .EXE that will **not terminate** when the python script terminates? The function must also not wait for the .EXE to terminate or exit.

Thanks for reading.

I tried subprocess.Popen, subprocess.run and subprocess.call w/o luck yet.

[Edit]
I'm running python v3.11 on W10.

[Edit2]

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>python
Python 3.11.2 (tags/v3.11.2:878ead1, Feb  7 2023, 16:38:35) [MSC v.1934 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import subprocess
>>> _npd = r'C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe'
>>> with open('d:\output.log', 'w') as outfile:
...     subprocess.Popen([_npd],
...         stdout=outfile,
...         stderr=outfile,
...         stdin=subprocess.DEVNULL,
...         detach=True
...     )
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
TypeError: Popen.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'detach'
>>>
```

What am I missing?

[Edit3]

It's getting crazy. This works perfectly well on CLI:

```
import subprocess
import sys
def myStartAPP(cmd):
    return subprocess.Popen(
        cmd,
        creationflags=subprocess.DETACHED_PROCESS
        )


_npd = r'C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe'
_file = r'mytext.txt'
_notepad = [_npd, _file]
_calc = [r'C:\Windows\System32\calc.exe']

print(sys.version)
p1 = myStartAPP(_notepad)
p2 = myStartAPP(_calc)
exit()
```

Both apps remain open.

But when I run the very same code within vscodium, only calc.exe remains open, notepad.exe gets closed. Whatever app is started first.
I also get:

> D:_Testing Ground> c: && cd "d:_Testing Ground" && cmd /C
> ""C:\ProgramFiles\Python311\python.exe"
> c:\Users\nn.vscode-oss\extensions\ms-python.python-2023.4.0-universal\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\adapter/../..\debugpy\launcher
> 60245 -- "d:_Testing Ground\start-APP.py" "
> 3.11.2 (tags/v3.11.2:878ead1, Feb  7 2023, 16:38:35) [MSC v.1934 64 bit (AMD64)]
> Exception ignored in: <function Popen.**del** at
> 0x000001ABFB823E20> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\subprocess.py", line 1128, in **del**
> self._internal_poll(_deadstate=_maxsize)
> File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\subprocess.py", line 1530, in _internal_poll
> if _WaitForSingleObject(self._handle, 0) == _WAIT_OBJECT_0:
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> OSError: [WinError 6] >The handle is invalid.

sys.version is precisely the same in CLI and vscodium. I begin to realize that **sub**process is the wrong way to go.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: I think the `creationflags` argument is the way to go. As you said it still fails with that, the issue might be the stdout/stderr redirection to a file handled by a python context manager. I suspect Notepad might close or crash when its stdout/err are closed, which is what should happen when the python program exits; or maybe because you're passing `DEVNULL` as stdin. Try executing the `Popen` call with just the `DETACHED_PROCESS` flag and no stdin/out/err arguments to see if that changes anything.

Comment: *I begin to realize that subprocess is the wrong way to go.* I do not think so. But VsCode (or VsCodium) is an editor that can be improved with addons that try to make a true IDE with it. What it is not. If you only have a simple linear program with a single thread in a single process everything is fine. When you have multiple processes, the addons may stop a process when you would not expect, simply because the author decided to clean up every process that has been launched during a session. Unfortunately such behaviour is seldom documented in VSCode addons...

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `start` command, which is part of the command shell.

```
def myStartAPP(cmd):
    cmd = ['cmd', '/c', 'start'] + cmd
    return subprocess.Popen(
        cmd,
        creationflags=subprocess.DETACHED_PROCESS
        )
```

If you don't like hard-coding the command shell, you can look it up:

```
import os
cmd_exe = os.environ['ComSpec']

def myStartAPP(cmd):
    cmd = [cmd_exe, '/c', 'start'] + cmd
    return subprocess.Popen(
        cmd,
        creationflags=subprocess.DETACHED_PROCESS
        )
```